# Azure DevOps server 2020 1.1 Pool type not available when creating agent pool

Tags: azure, server, devops, pool, agent

I am trying to create Scale set agent in azure devops 2020.

When reading the documentation it states that you can change to pool type to "viritual machine scale set" but i dont have that option.
Here is an image of adding a pool: [Add agent pool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWk81.png)

Is this not supported in the Server version, or do you need to configure something first?